# Amazon web Services actual Storage procedure

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-rds

what is the necessity to provide different storage types in AWS?
in which scenarios will use S3/EBS/RDS in AWS??

Comment: Well, RDS is a database and S3 is for files?

Answer (score 0):

**Amazon S3** is an object store. It can store any number of objects (files), each up to 5TB. Objects are replicated between Availability Zones (Data Centers) within a region. Highly reliable, high bandwidth, fully managed. Can also serve static websites without a server. A great places for storing backups or files that you want to share.

**Amazon Elastic Block Store (EBS)** is a virtual disk for Amazon EC2 instances, when a local file system is required.

**Amazon RDS** is a managed database. It installs and maintains a MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle or Microsoft SQL Server database as a managed service.

There are more storage services such as **DynamoDB**, which is a fully-managed NoSQL database service that provides fast and predictable performance with seamless scalability; **DocumentDB** that provides MongoDB-compatible storage; **Amazon Neptune**, which is a graph database; **Amazon Redshift**, which is a petabyte-scale data warehouse; **ElastiCache**, which is a fully-managed Redis or Memcached caching service; etc.

The world of IT has created many different storage options, each of which serves a different purpose or sweet-spot.